# Python xml-rpc with PHP client and unicode not working

Tags: php, python, mysql, curl, utf-8

I have XML-RPC Server written with Python. It takes some values and saves them in a mysql database. Data are in utf-8 and the whole process works fine.

I have no problem talking to it with other languages like Python and ASP.NET and C#, but when it comes to PHP, there is a problem. The characters are not being saved in MySQL as they should be and they are all scrambled characters.

I have done all the recommendations as setting the header in the PHP file and etc. I have also configured MySQL collation to utf-8, but the problem still exists.

The Curl used is from Github: https://github.com/dongsheng/cURL

Source code is below:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');

require_once('curl.php');
$rpc = "http://xmlrpc-webservice-address.com/";
$client = new xmlrpc_client($rpc, true);
$text="سلام";
$arr1=array("username", "password", array("111"), $text, "30002240123456", "ws", False);
$resp = $client->call('send', $arr1);
print_r($resp);
print_r("\n");
print_r($text);
?>
```

Comment: When you say "I have no problem talking to it…", which "it" are you referring to? The Python XML-RPC server, the MySQL database, or something else?

Comment: You seem to have just thrown random things at the problem to try to fix it. For example, what would you expect `mysql_set_charset('utf8')` in a script that doesn't do any MySQL anything?

Comment: I have no problem talking to it with C#, ASP.net and python on the client side and no problem saving the data as it should be in the mysql database, as I have access to both the server and the client.the only problem is using php as client and the data is not saved in the database as it should be ... every thing else is working fine.

Comment: "in a script that doesn't do any MySQL anything" , you were right, as I was going any possible way to solve the problem, this was my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your problem is one of the following (in descending order of likelihood):

- Your PHP source code isn't actually encoded as UTF-8, but as, say, CP1256. That means the non-ASCII literal string in the source is actually mojibake nonsense as far as the PHP interpreter, which reads it as UTF-8, is concerned. And those garbage bytes get passed through as-is all the way through the chain—to the XML-RPC service and back, to the browser, and to the user's screen.
- Your PHP source code *is* encoded as UTF-8, but your PHP interpreter thinks it's, say, CP1256, because of the way it (or your server/module) is configured. So, once again, the literal string is mojibake (in the opposite direction), which again passes through the whole chain.
- Your web service isn't returning UTF-8, but, say, Latin-1, and your other clients all treat it accordingly as Latin-1, but your PHP client code just assumes it's UTF-8, passes it to the browser as if it were UTF-8, and the user sees garbage.

---

If you're not absolutely, positively sure that your editor saved the source code as UTF-8, look at the source file in a hex editor. If it's UTF-8, the Arabic string should look like `D8 B3 D9 84 D8 A7 D9 85`. If it's anything different—like `D3 E1 C7 E3` (CP1256) or `D3 E3 C7 E5` (ISO-8859-6), that's your problem.

Comment: Yes, it's absolutely Arabic, no problem with that.

Comment: @Saied_Delshad: "It's absolutely Arabic" is not what I asked. Is your Arabic source code stored as UTF-8, CP1256, ISO-8859-6, or something different?

Comment: it is exactly : D8 B3 D9 84 D8 A7 D9 84

Comment: @Saied_Delshad: OK, so on to the second possibility. Is the PHP interpreter reading your source as UTF-8, or as something different, and then converting it to UTF-8? One way to tell this is to have the Python XML-RPC server log the bytes it receives and make sure they're the same bytes you thought you were sending.

Comment: thank's for the debugging way. unfortunately the data received is not utf-8. the string should be "سلام" but instead it's "Ø³ÙØ§ÙØ§Ø¨Ø§Ù" and the source is "C3 98 C2 B3 C3 99 C2 84 ..."

Comment: but when I check the string on the server side with type(inputstring) it still returns unicode ??!!

Comment: any help will be appreciated

Comment: @Saied_Delshad: The reason the server thinks the type is `unicode` is that it's already (incorrectly) decoded it to Unicode by the time you're checking it. Without knowing what your server code looks like or what frameworks/libraries you're using, I can't say where that's happening. But it sounds like that's the problem. Meanwhile, where are you getting the "C3 98 …" from?

Comment: @Saied_Delshad: Anyway, I still suspect your initial problem is on the PHP side (the #2 possibility in the answer)—your source file is saved as UTF-8, but PHP is reading it as, say, CP1256 and sending something like "ط³ظ„ط§ظ…" instead of "سلام". Again, we need to see the actual bytes that get sent over the wire, and `print inputstring` in the Python server is probably too late. Can you set up a [netcat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat) proxy, or [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org) the connection?